# Ajax URLs without #!, how to prevent falling into single.php on load or reload?

Tags: php, theme-development, ajax, javascript, redirect

I'm trying to make things properly with a single page ajax powered portfolio. I've read that there is no need of `#!` to make it crawlable by google. So I have clean URLs that updates with `.pushState` when I load a post.

My problem is that if you hit F5 or load directly an URL, you fall into the single.php.
You can try it yourself here: `http://www.youpiemonday.com/`

How can I prevent falling into the article page?

I thought about redirecting from the single.php to the home and trigger the opening of the post there. But seing the comments, it doesn't seems to be a great idea. Anyway I'm stuck right now... You can see my thought process on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896128/check-referrer-and-find-the-href-that-leads-to-it-then-trigger-a-click-with-jav).

I'd love to here some feedback from Wordpress specialists... :)

---

**EDIT:** I may have found a simple/quick way to redirect to the homepage if the request is done when on single.php. I simply added this to function.php

```
add_action('wp', 'RedirecToPost'); 
 function RedirecToPost(){ 
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']=='' && is_single()){ // if http request AND on single.php 
            wp_redirect( home_url() ); // redirect to home
            // THEN check the post requested AND trigger a click on its thumbnail

        }
  }
```

But I'm still at the same point. I need a way to check what was the requested post and trigger a click on its thumbnail. Now I'm really stuck by my scripting knowledge. How can I check the last page url (referer?) and find the href pointing to it in the current page?

Answer (score 1):

In short: do not use a `single.php`. If you only have a `index.php`, than all posts are displayed with this template because WP can not find any other template to display the content.

Your problem in a human language:

- If the url is `www.youpiemonday.com`, load the frontpage (index.php, home.php or what else)
- If the url is `www.youpiemonday.com` with a parameter, than display the single post within the parameter with `single.php`.

That's what WordPress will do because `youpiemonday.com/singlepost/` will be transformed (internaly) by WP into `www.youpiemonday.com/?p=123` (where `123` is the post ID of `singlepost`)

So what you will do is this:

Everytime someone called `www.youpiemonday.com`, render the frontpage (index.php, home.php, ...) with no single post in the portfolio opened. **But** if there is a paramter in the url (/singlepost/ ), than render the frontpage **and** open that single post (if available).

Delete or rename your single.php to force WP to use the index.php of your theme to display every kind of posts. To trigger the click, you can add a switch in your functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'trigger_click_on_single_post' );

function trigger_click_on_single_post(){

$js_template = '

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery( document ).ready(

  function( $ ){

  // create the js to trigger the link here
     LinktoRef = $(".ProjectWrap" ).find( "a" ).href; // the href in the thumbnail

     if ( "{{link_to_click}}" === LinktoRef ){
       find( "a" ).trigger( "click" );
     }

   }

);

</script>

';


  if( is_single() ){

    global $post;

    $replace = get_permalink(); // create the propper url here

    $js_output = str_replace( '{{link_to_click}}', $replace, $js_template );

    echo $js_output;

  }
}
```

PS: I don't not why, but the code formatting on WPSE don't like the heredoc syntax. So there is a litte break in the codeblock.

Comment: Great, some human language finally! :) Yes open/reload home.php AND THEN look for the parameter/post seems to be a gook workaround. I try to adapt it to my site but there's a few things I don't understand. What does `$js_template = <<<JS` and `JS;` mean or what am I supposed to replace it with? And the script is closed but there is no opening tag. BTW, will Googlebot be able to index the article anyway?

Comment: `$js_template = <<<JS ... JS;` is a heredoc syntax (http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), I use it because I have not to fiddle around with single&double qoutes.
Yes, the google bot will index the article as any other page.

Comment: Thx, just saw your update. The javascript part is greyish in notepad++ so I'm not sure it's declared the right way. To clarify, why would using index.php be different from using single.php (it seems to act the same way when single is deleted)? As I learn programming, something remains unclear. Will your code keep user on a single page navigation? What is `{link_to_click}`? Sorry lots of questions, maybe we could switch to chat when StackExchange propose (I don't have enough priviledges to create a room)...

Comment: I'm sorry. But I am only sporadic connected to the internet and write my answers and comments in short breaks from my truck. The chat is no option for me.
The js part is greed out because it is a string. `{link_to_click}` is just a placeholder (wll be replaced with `str_replace()`). Normally single.php is for displaying single posts, index.php for displaying the start page (home page).
What do you mean with "single page navigation"?
Sorry for the short answer, I have not a lot of time left.

Comment: I didn't meant "realtime" chat, but if you can't I understand, no problem. By single page navigation, I mean that all content has to be loaded on the homepage, even the sitelinks displayed on search engines. Nobody should see the single post page except Googlebot which (if I understood) will treat it as an html snapshot of the ajax loaded content. In my case, I use single.php as a structure for the posts. When the ajax load is triggered, I'm loading the whole single.php template (minus the header and footer) in the home.php. Maybe confusing, isn't it?